# PHP Cant get the count of array child elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the count and values of stocklevels from the following

```
Array ( [barcodes] => Array ( [barcode] => 10011010009 ) [basePrice] => 25.00 [customFields] => Array ( ) [description] => CBC-CBCJSW [discontinued] => false [PLU] => CBC Boy's Shirt 20 [priceLevels] => Array ( ) [primaryCategory] => CBC- Boys Shirts [productLineName] => CBC Boy's Shirt 20 [promptPOSOperatorForPrice] => false [sellByWeightOption] => false [stock] => Array ( [stockLevel] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [outletExportCode] => Level1 [stockCount] => 500.000000 ) [1] => Array ( [outletExportCode] => Level2 [stockCount] => 1000.000000 ) ) ) [taxes] => Array ( [taxName] => GST ) )
```

I have tried the following and i get 1 as the count all the time even if there are 2 levels in the array:

```
 count($ra['stock']['stockLevel']['stockCount']);
 count($ra['stock']['stockLevel']);
```

Also, i am trying to loop through the results to get teh stockcount but it doesnt seem to work:

```
    $stockLevelArr[] = $ra['stock'];
        $totalStock = 0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($stockLevelArr);$i++){

        echo $ra['productLineName'] . ' - Stock outside IF: ' . (int) $stockLevelArr[$i]['stockLevel']['stockCount'];
        echo '<br>';

        if (isset($stockLevelArr[$i]['stockLevel']['stockCount'])) {
            $totalStock = $totalStock + $stockLevelArr[$i]['stockLevel']['stockCount'];
        }
    }

    echo 'Stock count: ' . $totalStock;
    echo '<br>';
```

var dump

```
array(13) { ["barcodes"]=> array(1) { ["barcode"]=> string(11) "10011010009" } ["basePrice"]=> string(5) "25.00" ["customFields"]=> array(0) { } ["description"]=> string(10) "CBC-CBCJSW" ["discontinued"]=> string(5) "false" ["PLU"]=> string(18) "CBC Boy's Shirt 20" ["priceLevels"]=> array(0) { } ["primaryCategory"]=> string(16) "CBC- Boys Shirts" ["productLineName"]=> string(18) "CBC Boy's Shirt 20" ["promptPOSOperatorForPrice"]=> string(5) "false" ["sellByWeightOption"]=> string(5) "false" ["stock"]=> array(1) { ["stockLevel"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["outletExportCode"]=> string(13) "Tara Uniforms" ["stockCount"]=> string(10) "500.000000" } [1]=> array(2) { ["outletExportCode"]=> string(3) "CBC" ["stockCount"]=> string(11) "1000.000000" } } } ["taxes"]=> array(1) { ["taxName"]=> string(3) "GST" } }
```

I will appreciate any help.

UPDATE: Following worked. Thanks everyone for your replies and assistance.

```
    $totalStock = 0;

    $times_found = 0;
    $stock = $ra['stock'];
    foreach($stock['stockLevel'] as $stock_level) {
        if(isset($stock_level['stockCount'])) {
            $times_found++;
            $totalStock = $totalStock + $stock_level['stockCount'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try this: `count($ra, COUNT_RECURSIVE);` see also the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Please show us the array with `var_dump` instead of `print_r`

Comment: When you say you are 'trying to get the count', do you mean you want to know how many times in the array that it's used?

Comment: edited post and added var dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you want to know how many times `stockCount` is within the array? If so, I'd use array to loop through each index of the array and increment a variable each time it's found. For example:

```
$times_found = 0;
foreach($ra['stock'] as $stock) {
    foreach($stock['stockLevel'] as $stock_level) {
        if(isset($stock_level['stockCount'])) {
            $times_found++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and times_found comes up as 0

Comment: @VishalPatel If `times_found` is coming up as 0 it either means that there is nothing in the array, or the loop parameters are incorrect, I suspect the latter. Check that the naming is correct for each array parameter within the `foreach` loops.

Comment: Thanks. managed to get it read 2 stock levels by removing the outer loop.
Just trying to get the stock count now.

Comment: Managed to get it to work now by editing your code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. What did you have to change?

Comment: Updated the code above. However, there is a problem. when there is less than 2 stocklevel, the script does not enter the if statement

Answer (score 1):

You should count recursive to get all the keys in the count:

`count($ra, COUNT_RECURSIVE);`

See also the php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

And I think you should change your for loop to this:

```
<?php

$totalStock = 0;


foreach ($ra['stock'] as $stock) {

   echo $ra['productLineName'] . ' - Stock outside IF: ' . (int) $stock['stockLevel']['stockCount'];
   echo '<br>';

   if (isset($stock['stockLevel']['stockCount'])) {
       $totalStock = $totalStock + $stock['stockLevel']['stockCount'];
   }
}

echo 'Stock count: ' . $totalStock;
echo '<br>';
```

Instead of the for loop, dont know why you did use that, you better use the foreach in this example.

Comment: Tried this aswell. Still getting 0 stock.

Comment: I had no idea `count()` had a recursive flag. You learn something new every day :)